# DataFrame to XML Conversion: Price Value Multiplication Issue in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm encountering an issue while working with pandas in Python. I have a script that receives a DataFrame containing product details, prices, and other information. My goal is to convert this DataFrame into an XML format to subsequently send it to a database. There are additional processes involved in this workflow.

The problem arises when handling the 'price' field. The expected price value is 336117.6. However, during the conversion or insertion process, the value seems to be getting multiplied by 10, resulting in 3.361.176.

Here's a snippet of the XML structure:

```
<row>
        <Price>336117.6</Price>
</row>
```

To address this issue, I tried converting the 'Price' column to a numeric type using the pd.to_numeric function as follows:

```
df['preço'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Preço'], errors='coerce',)
```

Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue, and the behavior remains consistent.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adjusting the currency configurations on my Windows system.